# Use of graduate degree in signature

Tags: professionalism

8 years after I received my Masters I can say that I am finally in a job that at least *kinda* uses my degree.  I noticed that there are some project managers who have MBA after their name in their signature block.

Is there any common convention that says MBA is appropriate but MIS (Masters in Information Systems) is not?

Comment: Actually, it's not considered appropriate to list MBA after your name.  That doesn't stop people from doing it.

Answer (score 2):

No there is nothing stopping you using MIS in your signature block if you want to. It actually looks better than MBA to me, but mileage may vary I guess.